# C++: does boost::asio:write() not support UDP sockets?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Trying to use `boost::asio::write()` to write to a `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` object.  While I'm busy re-reading the docs to see if I've gone wrong somewhere, can someone confirm if maybe this is not supported?  I'm now thinking `boost::asio::write()` only supports `tcp::socket` objects, not `udp::socket`.

This is what I get when I try to compile:

```
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/write.ipp: In function ‘size_t
boost::asio::write(SyncWriteStream&, const ConstBufferSequence&, [...cut...]
test/test.cpp:76:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/write.ipp:44: error: ‘class
boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<boost::asio::ip::udp,
boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp> >’ has no member named
‘write_some’
```

I think I decided to try `boost::asio::write()` when I read this in the docs:

> The send operation may not transmit all of the data to the peer. Consider using
>   the write function if you need to ensure that all data is written before the
>   blocking operation completes.`

...but in going back, I see that text is only in `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::send()` and not in the UDP version.  [Source.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/send/overload3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want synchronous behavior, you need to use the [send](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/send.html) or [send_to](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/send_to.html) member methods of the `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` class. The `boost::asio::write` free function uses the [SyncWriteStream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SyncWriteStream.html) type requirement, which a UDP socket does not meet.

Answer (score 1):

I use `async_send_to` instead. Perhaps that's possible for you too?

```
void MyUdpServer::sendMessage(Message& message)
{
    m_message = message;

    m_socket.async_send_to(
        asio::buffer(&m_message, sizeof(m_message)), m_endpoint,
        boost::bind(&MyUdpServer::handle_send_to, shared_from_this(), 
        asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

where `m_socket` is an `asio::ip::udp::socket`.

Comment: No, I'm trying to stay away from the async calls if possible to prevent excessive code changes.  Your suggestion of a different API is appreciated, but if anything I'd use boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::send().

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that asio::write requires the stream class to have write_some implemented.
IIRC, When writing to UDP sockets you want to write everything at one time in order to reduce fragmentation (unless your data + UDP header + ip header size is > PMTU, then you've got some work ahead of you).

Do you have code on the receiving side that reorders/reassembles the UDP packets?  You will get UDP packets out of order and fragmented no matter how good your network is.

Comment: Out-of-order is not a problem.  I just want to write to a udp socket, but couldn't figure out why boost::asio::write() was giving me a compile-time error.